# How can I delete Azure B2C users directly from my app?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm building an ASP .Net Core web App. I use Azure ADB2C for user authentication and I would like to have an admin user, which could delete other users. I can delete users from Azure Active Directory via Azure portal, but I would like to do it directly from the app. I have created an admin account in my Active Directory tenant, and gave it global administrator permissions.

I tried to use Graph API, but I can't get it to work. I created an IAuthenticationProved according to instructions on this website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS.

Then I created GraphServiceClient and tried to delete user (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), but I got error:

> System.AggregateException: 'Returning 0 accountsts and 0 broker accountsdata provider for login.microsoftonline.com. Success? True.)'

> AuthenticationException: Code: authenticationChallengeRequired
> Message: Authentication challange is required.

My code looks like this:

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("<My Client ID>")
            .WithRedirectUri("<My Redirect Uri>")
            .WithClientSecret("<My Client secret>") 
            .Build();
            List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
            scopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All");
            scopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/Directory.ReadWrite.All");
            AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication,scopes);


            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);


            graphClient.Users[<UserId>]
                .Request()
                .DeleteAsync()
                .Wait();
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe there is some other way to do it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to use Graph API is the way to go. But the problem you are facing there is because your selected auth provider (AuthorizationCodeProvider) is not matching with the scope needed here to delete user. Looking at your code, you want 'Authorization Code' flow which means it would need a delegated scope. As mentioned in [permission requirement for delete user](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/user-delete#permissions), the 'Delegated' scope needed to delete user is `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` which I don't see in the code snippet you shared.

Additionally, suggest you a quick read to [Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider based on scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers).

NOTE: To add the required delegated permission, the application registration must be either of the first two types types shown below. The third option won't give you that.
[image]
For the above you will be able to add `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` delegated permission.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but I got one more question. Should I add some API permission to my app via Azure Portal? Because when I go to the Azure portal -> Azure ADB2C -> app registrations -> myApp -> API permissions -> Add a permission -> Microsoft Graph -> Delegated permissions i don't see any other permissions to grant than "offline_access" and "openid". I tried to add Directory.AccessAsUser.All scope to my code, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes you need to add API permission to the app registration. Ahh, I see why you don't see `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` there. Check the appended NOTE in the answer.

Comment: Okay, but if I understand correctly, if I don't choose the third option, I cannot use B2C for authenticating users. So I registered another app in my tenant with the first option, created client secret for it and put it along with its clientID into my code, but I still get this error about required authentication challenge. Thank you for helping me!