# How Can I Check Azure AD B2C Delete Permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, azure-ad-b2c

I have two Azure AD B2C accounts. With the same source code, I can remove a user from the test environment but it doesn't allow me to remove any objects from the production environment.

I checked the API Permissions for my application. Both of them have the same permissions and also I checked the ClientId, ClientSecret etc.

Are there any pages where I can see more permissions / configurations or logs?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean that you have an application used SDK to remove the user? If so, which language you use? Asp.net core? And which api you used to remove user?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to remove via the Azure function (.Net Core).

Comment: How do you think about using azure application insights to collect logs for it? And maybe you can provide your code snippet and other details to let us analyze it.

Comment: The source wasn't developed by me and It doesn't use application insights at the moment. Same code snippet is working for test environment and preprod.

Comment: Therefore, we should focus on the environment itself? I mean ,the production environment may have some policy to prevent users be deleted but the test environment doesn't have?

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can check the application permissions of your application in test environment as well as in production environment through the Microsoft Graph API as follows. Also, please remember that in order for your application to get permissions to delete users from Azure AD B2C, your application would need ‘Directory.AccessAsUser.All’ permissions.

1. Get the object ID of the service principal based on App ID: - ‘ GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq ‘{App ID}’ ‘
2. Get the App Role information (the application permission information) based on the Object ID from step 1: ‘ GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{Object](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/%7BObject) ID}/appRoleAssignedTo ‘
3. Get a match list of appRoleID and Microsoft Graph application permission name: ‘ GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' ‘

•   The AppID of ‘'00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000’ is the AppID of Microsoft Graph API. Once the three commands are run successfully, compare the results of 2nd and 3rd step to know the permissions of your application and Microsoft Graph API and compare accordingly. Also, you can compare the permissions of your application in test environment and production environment through this also.

•   You can also check the audit logs for your application in production environment to get more information about user access and activity regarding it. Please check whether global admin consent is provided for your Azure function(.Netcore) or not for required permission scopes.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

[How can I delete Azure B2C users directly from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65061634/how-can-i-delete-azure-b2c-users-directly-from-my-app)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Thank you.